# How to query with EXISTS Clause with Sequelize?

Tags: orm, sequelize.js, psql

How can we use EXISTS clause in sequelize such that it fires a query in the following manner ?
`IF EXISTS(SELECT FIRSTNAME FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE FIRSTNAME LIKE 'JOHN%')`
This might be done by inserting the same query in the `.query()` method, but is there any way we can use EXISTS Clause in the `findOne()` method ?.

Answer (score 4):

You can construct a `sequelize literal` like below -

```
where: {
      [op.and]: [Sequelize.literal('exists ( SELECT FIRSTNAME FROM `EMPLOYEES` WHERE `EMPLOYEES`.`FIRSTNAME` LIKE 'JOHN%' )')]
    },
```

Hope it helps!