# Using EXISTS with bound parameters in sub-query with Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, jsonb

Suppose I have a table of something like cars, where inside is a JSONB object specifying possible customizations:

```
+----+-----------------------------------------+
| id | customizations JSONB                    |
+----+-----------------------------------------+
| 1  | {"color": "blue", "lights": "led", ...} |
+----+-----------------------------------------+
| 2  | {"color": "red"}                        |
+----+-----------------------------------------+
| 3  | {}                                      |
+----+-----------------------------------------+
```

If I want to query for a certain customization based on case-insensitive value or partial value (i.e., `ILIKE`), I can do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM "Cars" WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM JSONB_EACH_TEXT("customizations") WHERE "value" ~* 'BLU'
);
```

This pattern works fine in Postgres, but now I am trying to translate it over to Sequelize as best as I can.  The important thing here is that the search term ('BLU' from the example) is passed as a parameter.

```
const cars = await cars.findAll({
  where: // ????  Maybe something like db.fn('EXISTS', ...), but how do I bind the parameter?
});
```

How can I use an `EXISTS` query here, but bind a parameter?  I know I [could use `db.literal()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61202300/362536), but if I did that, I'd have to escape the search term string myself before interpolating it into the query.  (Is there at least a proper method for doing this data escaping in Sequelize?)

Note that the JSONB object in `customizations` can have many keys, a single key, or even no keys.

**Bounty Note:** Answers using modern versions of Postgres are fine, but I would also like an answer for PostgreSQL v10.12, as that's all that is available with AWS Aurora Serverless.  I'll happily assign a separate bounty to both answers!

Comment: Does JSONB_EACH_TEXT("customizations") has 1 or several records?

Comment: @Anatoly It can have several.  Some of these "cars" may only have one (or zero) matching customizations, others may have like 10+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If on postgresql 12+, it would be possible to use the json path expression to extract all values & cast to text in order to regex match

The raw query would be

```
SELECT *
FROM cars
WHERE jsonb_path_query_array(customizations, '$.*')::TEXT ~* 'BLU'
```

in sequelize:

```
where: Sequelize.where(
  Sequelize.literal("jsonb_path_query_array(customizations, '$.*')::TEXT"),
  Op.iRegexp,
  'BLU'
)
```

On older versions, i would probably use a raw query with bound parameters that maps back to the `Car` object.

> How can I use an EXISTS query here, but bind a parameter? I know I could use db.literal(), but if I did that, I'd have to escape the search term string myself before interpolating it into the query. (Is there at least a proper method for doing this data escaping in Sequelize?)

you can bind parameters to raw sql queries using either `$1` or `$name` for positional (array) and named (object) arguments.

```
// cars.js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const path = 'postgresql://hal:hal@localhost:5432/hal'

const sequelize = new Sequelize(path);

let Car = sequelize.define('cars', {
        id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true },
        customizations: Sequelize.JSONB
});

let cars = [{ id: 1, customizations: {color: "blue", lights: "led"} },
            { id: 2, customizations: {color: "red"} },
            { id: 3, customizations: {} }]


const search_pat = 'BLU';

const stmt = `
select distinct cars.*
from cars, jsonb_each_text(customizations) kv(kk, vv)
where vv ~* $search_pattern
`;

sequelize
    .sync()
    .then(() => {
        Car.bulkCreate(cars)
    })
    .then(() => {
        sequelize.query(stmt, {
            bind: {search_pattern: search_pat},
            type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT,
            model: Car,
            mapToModel: true
        }).then(cars => {console.log(cars);})
});
```

executing this script (`node cars.js`) produces the following output:

```
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "cars" ("id" INTEGER , "customizations" JSONB, "createdAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'cars' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "cars" ("id","customizations","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (1,'{"color":"blue","lights":"led"}','2021-04-14 04:42:50.446 +00:00','2021-04-14 04:42:50.446 +00:00'),(2,'{"color":"red"}','2021-04-14 04:42:50.446 +00:00','2021-04-14 04:42:50.446 +00:00'),(3,'{}','2021-04-14 04:42:50.446 +00:00','2021-04-14 04:42:50.446 +00:00') RETURNING "id","customizations","createdAt","updatedAt";
Executing (default): select distinct cars.*
from cars, jsonb_each_text(customizations) kv(kk, vv)
where vv ~* $1
[
  cars {
    dataValues: {
      id: 1,
      customizations: [Object],
      createdAt: 2021-04-14T04:42:50.446Z,
      updatedAt: 2021-04-14T04:42:50.446Z
    },
    _previousDataValues: {
      id: 1,
      customizations: [Object],
      createdAt: 2021-04-14T04:42:50.446Z,
      updatedAt: 2021-04-14T04:42:50.446Z
    },
    _changed: Set(0) {},
    _options: {
      isNewRecord: false,
      _schema: null,
      _schemaDelimiter: '',
      raw: true,
      attributes: undefined
    },
    isNewRecord: false
  }
]
```

note that i've used an alternative (and likely less efficient select statement in the example above)

You can use your original query, which IMO is the most straight-forward query for the target postgresql version (10.x), i.e.

```
const stmt = `
SELECT * 
FROM cars 
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM JSONB_EACH_TEXT(customizations) WHERE "value" ~* $search_pattern
)
`;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I can use modern Postgres for most of my projects, but I have one case where I also need to be compatible with v10.12.  Do you by chance have an alternative answer you can post for older Postgres?  If so, please post as a second answer and I'll happily give a bounty to both.

Comment: on older versions, i'd probably go the route of raw query with bound parameter. See updated answer for a fully working script with an alternative. also note that bound parameters don't need to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

If you modify your condition like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM "Cars" WHERE (
  SELECT "value" FROM JSONB_EACH_TEXT("customizations")) ~* 'BLU'
```

then you can use `Sequelize.where` in a conjunction with `Sequelize.literal`:

```js
where: Sequelize.where(
Sequelize.literal('(SELECT "value" FROM JSONB_EACH_TEXT("customizations"))'),
Op.iRegexp,
'BLU'
)
```

**Upd.**
This solution will work only if a subquery returns 1 record.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Yes, I'm running into the trouble alluded to by your comment... "SequelizeDatabaseError: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression", since `JSONB_EACH_TEXT()` will return potentially many records.

Comment: Maybe you can use a string aggregation function to get 1 record in the subquery to use my solution

Comment: That's an idea... I'm looking into that now, thanks!